# How to sort a C# List with a Delegate

Tags: c#

I am trying to sort a list of structs in C#. The code is here:

```
void SortScores()
{
  Debug.Log(String.Format("Sorting Scores: {0}", scores.Count()));
  scores.Sort(delegate (LeaderboardScore x, LeaderboardScore y)
  {
    int scoreAsIntX = int.Parse(x.score);
    int scoreAsIntY = int.Parse(y.score);
    Debug.Log(String.Format("Comparing {0} with {1}", scoreAsIntX, scoreAsIntY));
    return scoreAsIntX.CompareTo(scoreAsIntY);
  });
}
```

And I run this after I have pulled all my data from Firebase, created the objects and added them all to my `scores` variable.

The logs for this show me that `scores` has a count of 23 objects, but the delegate only runs once and declares: `Comparing 239 with 270`

It doesn't seem to run through all of the items in the list and isn't sorting it as expected.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - note that it will be fine to hard-code the data, as `List<T>.Sort` doesn't care where the data came from.

Comment: Is it possible that `int.Parse` is throwing an exception, but you're not seeing it, for example?(As an aside, I'd recommend learning about interpolated string literals to make your logging simpler.)

Comment: That could be possible, actually ... I would need to set it to 0 in that case

Comment: If it is an `int.Parse` issue, you could see that easily by moving the `Debug.Log` statement above the parse code and then logging `$"Comparing {x.score} with {y.score}"`.  Consider using Lambda syntax rather than the `delegate` keyword; it's easier to read.  By the way, don't wrap the Parse code in Try/Catch, use `TryParse` instead

Comment: It was the parse. There were a couple of records with blank scores that were empty strings. Thank you for the help. I am new to C# so am curious, what is the Lambda syntax?

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to the commenters here. There were records that had empty strings as the scores so it wasn't doing the int parse. My updated code is:

```
scores.Sort(delegate (LeaderboardScore x, LeaderboardScore y)
{
 int scoreAsIntX = 0;
 int scoreAsIntY = 0;
 int.TryParse(x.score, out scoreAsIntX);
 int.TryParse(y.score, out scoreAsIntY);

 Debug.Log(String.Format("Comparing {0} with {1}", scoreAsIntX, scoreAsIntY));
 return scoreAsIntX.CompareTo(scoreAsIntY);
});
```